# ¿Cómo puedo validar que mi fecha de final "end_time" no sea menor que la fecha de inicio "start_time"?

Tags: django, djangorestframework

La idea es que cuando se inserte un nuevo registro, verificar que la fecha final no sea menor a la inicial, si es menor mandar un error y si no crear el registro

**Model**

```
from django.db import models


class Effort(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField('id')
start_time = models.DateTimeField()
end_time = models.DateTimeField()
comment = models.CharField('comment', max_length=255)
assignment_id = models.IntegerField('assignment_id')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'effort'
    verbose_name = 'effort'
    verbose_name_plural = 'efforts'
    ordering = ('-created_at',)

def natural_key(self):
    return self.id

@staticmethod
def get_object(id):
    try:
        return Effort.objects.get(id=id)
    except Effort.DoesNotExist:
        return False
```

En el serializador estan lo campos que se requieren para hacer el registro

**Serializaer**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rems.models.Effort import Effort

class EffortSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
assignment_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
comment = serializers.CharField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Effort
    fields = ('id', 'assignment_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'comment')
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir una una función que valide el campo `end_time` usando el prefijo `clean_`, y forzando que se llame siempre antes de guardar en la base de datos.

#### Ejemplo

```py
from django.db import models


class Effort(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(Effort, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean_end_time(self):
        if self.end_time < self.start_time:
            raise ValidationError('La fecha de termino debe ser mayor a la de inicio')
```

#### Documentación

- Validación de objetos: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects